# How to insert multiple values in SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I don't exactly know how to phrase the question, but an example would work. So I have this table

```
Users

Id          Name
1           Tim
2           Jon
3           Matt
```

There is another table

```
Tags

TagId       TagName
1           Test
2           Other
3           Dummy
4           More
```

In a temp table I have structure like this

```
TmpUserTags

User            Tags
Tim             Test
Jon             Other, Test
Matt            Dummy, More, Other
```

So, what I need to do is from this temp table, insert record in table `UserTags` with corresponding Ids, for the above given example, the result would be

```
UserTags

User                TagId
1                   1
2                   2
2                   1
3                   3
3                   4
3                   2
```

So, this is the end result I want, to be inserted in `UserTags`. But since for each row in `TmpUserTags` each user can have many tags, separated by comma, I don't know what would be the best way to do it. I can probably use a while loop (or rather a cursor) to loop through all the rows in `TmpUserTags`, and then, for each row, split the tags by comma, find their Id, and insert those in `UserTags`. But that doesn't seems to be the most optimized way. Can someone please suggest some better way of doing it?

Comment: Why is your TmpUserTags table structured like this ? On row for each tuple user / tag would be soooo easier...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus
I know, but it's not like that. It's exactly like the way I described, for one user multiple comma separated tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to just join the tags column using `LIKE`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Users (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(4));
INSERT #Users (ID, Name)
VALUES (1, 'Tim'), (2, 'Jon'), (3, 'Matt');

CREATE TABLE #Tags (TagID INT, TagName VARCHAR(5));
INSERT #Tags (TagID, TagName)
VALUES (1, 'Test'), (2, 'Other'), (3, 'Dummy'), (4, 'More');

CREATE TABLE #TmpUserTags ([User] VARCHAR(4), Tags VARCHAR(100));
INSERT #tmpUserTags ([User], Tags)
VALUES ('Tim', 'Test'), ('Jon', 'Other,Test'), ('Matt', 'Dummy,More,Other');

SELECT  u.ID, t.TagID 
FROM    #TmpUserTags AS ut
        INNER JOIN #Users AS u
            ON u.Name = ut.[User]
        INNER JOIN #Tags AS t
            ON ',' + ut.Tags + ',' LIKE '%,' + t.TagName + ',%';
```

You could also go down the route of creating a split function to split your comma separated list into rows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@StringToSplit NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter NCHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(   
    SELECT  ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n.Number),
            Position = Number,
            Value = SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, Number, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringToSplit + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
    FROM    (   SELECT  TOP (LEN(@StringToSplit) + 1) Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id)
                FROM    sys.all_objects a
            ) n
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @StringToSplit + @Delimiter, n.Number, 1) = @Delimiter
);
```

Then you can use:

```
SELECT  u.ID, t.TagID 
FROM    #TmpUserTags AS ut
        CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(ut.tags, ',') AS s
        INNER JOIN #Users AS u
            ON u.Name = ut.[User]
        INNER JOIN #Tags AS t
            ON t.TagName = s.Value;
```

Comment: Are you sure this like won't cause any problems with multiple tags?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I am just asking but I haven't used `LIKE` on a join before, seems like at some point later it might mess things up. Say, one tag is `Test`, and another tag is `Tested` won't `LIKE` cause problem in this case?

Comment: No, because the predicate adds commas to tag name `'%,' + t.TagName + ',%'` it limits it to exact matches, so as an example tags of "tag1,testing" have a comma added before and after to become ",tag1,testing," - so this won't match a tag of "test" because it is actually looking for ",test," - it will only match ",tag1," and ",testing,".

Answer (score 0):

Here is XML-version of answer:

```
SELECT Users.Id as [User],Tags.TagId
FROM 
 (SELECT A.[User],  
     LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS Tagname  
 FROM  (SELECT [User],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Tags, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  TmpUserTags) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) ut
LEFT JOIN Users ON Users.Name=ut.[User]
LEFT JOIN Tags ON Tags.TagName=ut.Tagname
```

No procedures, functions and CTEs.

**[Update]** If some performance issues are appeared, please read this nice article: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/114/posts/14617/delimited-string-tennis-anyone.aspx

Left join is used to show all rows from the table TmpUserTags even if other tables are w/o some necessary rows (E.g. new User 'Bob' with Tag 'Test2' that isn't described in table Tags)

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it (Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f48f/20):

```
WITH cteTagMatrix
AS
(
    SELECT  n.ID,
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX(',' + t.TagName + ',', REPLACE(',' + tut.Tags + ',', ' ', '')) <> 0 THEN t.TagID
                ELSE NULL
            END AS TagID
    FROM    Names n INNER JOIN TmpUserTags tut
            ON n.[Name] = tut.[User]
            CROSS JOIN Tags t
)

SELECT    *
FROM      cteTagMatrix
WHERE     TagID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  ID, TagID;)
```

**EDIT:**  Oops, was a error with my comma logic.  Fixed code and fiddle updated.

Answer (score 0):

To me the main question would be how you arrived at the temp table containing the comma delimited column. If it was an import from a file and all the data was comma delimited it would be easy enough to save the file as a csv which will save the user and each tag separately, then create a table in the your database containing the same number of columns as the file has, then bulk insert this table from the file.

```
drop table #TmpUserTags
GO
create table #TmpUserTags
(
[user] varchar(10),
tag1 varchar(10),
tag2 varchar(10),
tag3 varchar(10)
)
bulk insert #TmpUserTags from '<filepath>' with (fieldterminator=',')
```

Then union the data to create two columns which should be easy enough to reinterpret as ids.

```
SELECT [User],Tag1 FROM #TmpUserTags WHERE Tag1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [User],Tag2 FROM #TmpUserTags WHERE Tag2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [User],Tag3 FROM #TmpUserTags WHERE Tag3 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [User]
```

Of course all this might be conjecture but, like, how *did* you arrive at the table with the comma delimited values?

Comment: Nope, it's not fixed there there would only be 3 tags, so to create a table with 3 columns for tags is not gonna work.

Comment: It would be ok to create a table for as many tags as the incoming data has!

Comment: It's dynamic, not fixed size. Could be 2 could be 200

Comment: OK, just to see if I am on the right track, for example running this would establish the maximum number of tags you have in the delimited column: select max(len(tags) - len(replace(tags, ',', ''))) from #tmpusertags, does that seem useful?